# How to use ssh-copy-id to add the authorized_keys to specific user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, ansible

IN AWS `ec2-user` is the default user **and root account is disabled for login**

to create a new user first login with ec2-user then switch to root and then perform `adduser user1`

From the Remote Machine if i Login it should be in this sequence

```
ssh -i <privkey> ec2-user@<IPADDR>
sudo su
adduser user1
```

I'm struggling to find a way how to copy the `authorized_keys` using  `ssh-copy-id` with user `ec2-user` to update the user1 .ssh public keys

basically switch to `root` and update the desired user  `/home/user1/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Manually I can add the `authorized_keys` for each user by switching to root and then go to that user profile, is there any way to Automate through `ssh-copy-id`

```
ssh -i <privkey> ec2-user@<IPADDR>
sudo su
su - user1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a password for this user and the password authentication is allowed, you can use `ssh-copy-id` just as you do it with `ssh-copy-id -i <privkey> user1@<IPADDR>`.

Otherwise `ssh-copy-id` will not be helpful for you. But creating few lines script that will automate this job for you is probably a good way to go if you plan to add more users.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a cloud-init script in the instance user-data to add users and authorized_keys at first boot.

Take a look at AWS documentation about [User Data and cloud-init Directives](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html#user-data-cloud-init) and cloud-init documentation about [Including users and groups](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/examples.html#including-users-and-groups).

You can inject user-data with [Ansible `ec2` module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ec2_module.html).